# AngularJS plus/minus toggle

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to add plus/minus toggle on number input field when using `ng-repeat`

I tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in PC.Items">
  <button ng-click="PC.minus()" class='btn btn-default'>-</button>
            <input ng-model="item.Quantity"
                    type='number'
                    name='Quantity'/>
            <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="PC.plus()">+</button>
</div>

       vm.plus = function() {
            vm.Quantity++;
            console.log(vm.Quantity);
        };
        vm.minus = function() {
            vm.Quantity--;
        };
```

Thnx :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plus & minus buttons should only affect the current item they assigned to, not all the other items. To do so, pass the item instance to the plus and minus functions - because objects are passed as reference, the object data will be changed directly.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in PC.Items">
    <button ng-click="PC.minus(item)" class="btn btn-default">-</button>
    <input ng-model="item.Quantity" type="number" name="Quantity"/>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="PC.plus(item)">+</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
vm.plus = function(item) {
    item.Quantity++;
};
vm.minus = function(item) {
    item.Quantity--;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one line will do your requirement why to have more functions increase lines of code

HTML

```
 <button ng-click="countVal=countVal-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">  </i></button>
{{countVal}}
<button  ng-click="countVal=countVal+1"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">  </i> </button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$scope.countVal=0;
```

[**LIVEDEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/lMwtdM0GTAPCWIVdKTFw?p=preview)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your model reference variable is wrong that is PC and item

if it is PC than Updated code is

```
Your model reference variable is wrong that is PC and item
```

if it is PC than Updated code is

```
<div ng-repeat="item in PC.Items">
  <button ng-click="item.Quantity=item.Quantity+1" class='btn btn-default'>-</button>
            <input ng-model="item.Quantity"
                    type='number'
                    name='Quantity'/>
            <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="item.Quantity=item.Quantity-1">+</button>
</div>

       vm.plus = function() {
            vm.Quantity++;
            console.log(vm.Quantity);
        };
        vm.minus = function() {
            vm.Quantity--;
        };
```